# AS3 How to instantiate a class with getdefintionbyname and getqualifiedbyclass with TYPED declaration

Tags: actionscript-3

example:

var c : Class = Sprite; 
//This can be random class such as movieclip/etc

var o = getDefintionByName(getQualifiedClassName(c));

this works, but in flash develop, 
it says that the variable 'o' has no type declaration

which basically means

var o : SOMETHING = getDefintionByName(getQualifiedClassName(c));

but how do i put that something there when i do not know what its coming because of random classes?

Answer (score 0):

one solution would be using 
var o : * = getDefintionByName(getQualifiedClassName(c));

the asterick symbol is a temporary one, but it works

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface or a base class for the classes you wish to instantiate and then type the var to that.

```
var o:ICustomClass = ...
```

or

```
var o:BaseClass = ...
```